# Handle js button from C# UWP

Tags: javascript, c#, win-universal-app

I am new in windows and I want to handle a button that is into a `WebView`, when press button there is a js function to execute, and I need returned params in my C# class. In Android that is very easy, something like:

in `WebView` is loaded this code:

```
function sayHello(myParam) {
    BindJsInAndroid.sayHello(myParam);
}

<input type="button" value="My Button" onClick="sayHello('Hello world')" /><br/>
```

and in android code:

```
 WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
 MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface = new MyJavaScriptInterface(mActivityContext);
 webView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "BindJsInAndroid");


//into MyJavaScriptInterface class
 @JavascriptInterface
        public void sayHello(String myParam) {
            //here I get myParam
        }
```

Is there a way to do that in UWP?

**EDIT**

I tried as is mentioned on msdn [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.addweballowedobject.aspx) but can't get it work:

so my html src is:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function js_function() {
        bind_object.js_fun();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<input type="button" value="Button" onClick="js_function()" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and I have in my C# code:

```
public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();

     //load html src
     webView.NavigateToString(mas);

     //bind js with C#
     webView.AddWebAllowedObject("bind_object", new MyNativeClass());
        }

  [Windows.Foundation.Metadata.AllowForWeb]
    public sealed class MyNativeClass {
        public void js_fun() {
            Debug.WriteLine("get js function call");
                        }
        }
```

When I press button in webview I don't ge called `js_fun()` from C#...

Answer (score 3):

There's two ways to do that on UWP.

The first one is the [`WebView.ScriptNotify`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify) event. The event is raised whenever you call `window.external.notify` from the Javascript. It's quick and painless to use, but it has only one string parameter (so you need to do some parsing if you want to squeeze multiple values inside).

The second one requires a bit more work but is closer to the Android way. You can expose an object to the Javascript by calling [`WebView.AddWebAllowedObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.addweballowedobject.aspx) (so it works pretty much like your `webView.addJavascriptInterface`. But make sure to add the `AllowForWeb` attribute to your exposed class or it won't work.

Comment: @VasileDoe According to MSDN: The object passed into AddWebAllowedObject must be imported from a Windows Runtime component **that is separate from the app assembly**. This is necessary for the AllowForWeb attribute to be property identified by the WebView security subsystem. **If you use a class from your app project, AddWebAllowedObject does not work.**

Comment: ok, get it, but the main problem is that it works only if I inject script using `DOMContentLoaded` like: 


 `private async void DOMContentLoadedMethod(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args) {
            try {
               await Web.InvokeScriptAsync("name",new[] { "document.getElementById(\"myId\").addEventListener(\"click\", function () { bind_object.js_fun(); }); " });
               
            } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }`


but the purpose is to have that script into html, I'll need to retrieve params from js functions.